# Is there a way to simplify $(4)$ by factoring out $\varepsilon\Delta t$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, numerical-methods, stochastic-differential-equations, numerical-calculus

Start from a stochastic differential equation of the form:
$$dr_t=a(b-r_t)dt+\sigma\sqrt{r_t}dB_t\tag{1}$$
with $\left(B_t\right)_{t\geq0}$ denoting a Brownian motion on the filtered probability space $\left(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathcal{F}_n,\mathbb{P}\right)$. By property of Brownian motion, $(1)$ can be rewritten as:
$$dr_t=a(b-r_t)dt+\sigma\sqrt{r_tdt}Z\tag{2}$$
with $Z=\mathsf{N}(0,1)$ denoting a standard normal distribution, mean $0$ and standard deviation $1$.

---

---

I would like to numerically simulate the solution to $(2)$. To this, I could use for example Euler-Maruyama method, with simulation step-size equal to $\Delta t$, discretizing $(2)$ as follows:
$$r_{t+\Delta t}=r_{t}+a(b-r_t)\Delta t+\sigma\sqrt{r_t\Delta t}\mathsf{N}(0,1)\tag{3}$$

I would like to know the probability associated to the event (for a given $t$):
$$\mathbb{P}\left(r_{t+\Delta t}<0|r_{t}=\varepsilon\right)\hspace{1.5cm}\text{for }\varepsilon>0\text{ arbitrarily small}$$
In other terms, if I suppose that the value of the solution process at previous time is quite small, which is the probability that at next simulation step the solution process will lie below $0$?
After several passages, I get that:
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}\left(r_{t+\Delta t}<0\right)&=\mathbb{P}\left(\varepsilon+a(b-\varepsilon)\Delta t+\sigma\sqrt{\varepsilon \Delta t}Z<0\right)\\
&=1-\mathbb{P}\left(Z>-\dfrac{\sqrt{\varepsilon \Delta t}}{\sigma}\left(\dfrac{1}{\Delta t}+a\left(\dfrac{b}{\varepsilon}-1\right)\right)\right)\nonumber\\
&\underbrace{\leq}_{\text{by Chebyshev inequality}}1-\dfrac{\sigma^2 \Delta t \varepsilon}{\varepsilon^2+\left(\Delta t a b\right)^2+\left(a\varepsilon \Delta t\right)^2+2ab\Delta t\varepsilon-2a\varepsilon^2 \Delta t-2a^2\Delta t^2b\varepsilon}
\end{align}

At this point I would like to know if I can investigate the behaviour of $\mathbb{P}\left(r_{t+\Delta t}<0|r_{t}=\varepsilon\right)$ as $\varepsilon$ and/or $\Delta t$ vary (varies). Hence, in other terms, I would like to find an alternative (simplified) form for:
$$1-\dfrac{\sigma^2 \Delta t \varepsilon}{\varepsilon^2+\left(\Delta t a b\right)^2+\left(a\varepsilon \Delta t\right)^2+2ab\Delta t\varepsilon-2a\varepsilon^2 \Delta t-2a^2\Delta t^2b\varepsilon}\tag{4}$$
just to understand how $\mathbb{P}\left(r_{t+\Delta t}<0|r_{t}=\varepsilon\right)$ is affected by $\varepsilon$ and $\Delta$ (e.g. probability rises as $\varepsilon$ increases or probability lowers as $\Delta t$ increases, etc.)

Comment: The denominator of the big fraction factors as a perfect square. (You might suspect this, as it involves three squared terms and doubles of the products of the terms being squared; in particular, you have the form $x^2+y^2+z^2+2xy-2xz-2yz$. It's possible the signs on those products would prevent factoring, but it works out here.)

Comment: I don't think so. The denominator may be identified as a perfect square but that's about it. This is already in simplest form.

Comment: So, apart from simplification of denominator as a perfect square, no other simplification is possible? @Blue

Comment: @Strictly_increasing: *"no other simplification is possible?"* ... That would be my assessment. Of course,  you *could* combine the terms as $$\frac{(\cdots)^2-abc}{(\cdots)^2}$$ but this isn't what I'd call *simpler*. The "best" form of an expression usually depends upon what you intend to do with it. If this is the final result of some calculation, then I would probably just leave it as $1-\frac{abc}{(\cdots)^2}$.

Comment: OK. And if I wanted to write big fraction factoring out $bc$? @Blue

Comment: @Strictly_increasing: *"if I wanted to write big fraction factoring out $bc$?"* You could certainly write $$bc\cdot\frac{a}{(\cdots)^2}$$ but I'm not sure this is what you mean. It might help if you explained the larger context of this expression. (Do so by editing the question to add details. Comments are easily overlooked.)

Comment: Of course, I am going to edit my question. Thank you a lot @Blue

Comment: Just finished. I described the entire framework and changed notation. Hope it is as much clear as possible @Blue

Comment: I'm not sure if this helps, but letting $x:=\varepsilon, y:=\Delta t$, $(4)$ can be written as $$1-\frac{\sigma^2 y x}{(a b y - a x y + x)^2}$$ Let this be $f(x,y)$. Then, we have $$\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}=\frac{\sigma^2 y ( aby +axy - x)}{(axy - aby - x)^3}$$ and $$\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}=\frac{\sigma^2 x (-a b y + a x y + x)}{( a x y-a b y  - x)^3}$$